# Is it possible to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 all through ssh without being in front of my desktop?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I am currently unable to access my server computer at my office due to the whole Coronavirus situation but need to update my Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.04. I currently have ssh access and have not rebooted the computer in 3 months now. I am wondering if there was a way for me to set up ssh access even after restarting the computer and be able to login again to my computer. Would this work if I need to reboot the computer or must I physically be there? Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It **should** not be a problem. After update, 20.04 will honor the ssh settings from 18.04. But if something goes wrong, you cannot fix it. I would wait at least until 20.04.1. There is no need to update now, 18.04 is supported and if it was fine until now, why should you change that?

Comment: I am unable to run R 4.0.0, a statistical computing software due to a requirement of libc6 version >= 2.29. To reiterate, should I set up wake from lan and allow root login? Would these be enough to get an ssh after a restart?

Comment: If that is the only problem, [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and run 20.04 from a docker container ...